# How do I sort result set using a SOLR url?

Tags: json, solr, facet

I have the following URL:

```
http://webaddress:8994/solr/crossmedia/select?q=MEM_ED_NUMBER:136250%20AND%20CM_TYPE:WEB_MOBILE&rows=0&wt=json&indent=true&json.facet={Level1:{type:terms,field:ENTRY_DATE,limit:100,facet:{Level2:    {type:terms,field:NAME_URL,limit:100,facet:{sum:"sum(PAGE_IMPRESSIONS)",sum2:"sum(PAGE_IMPRESSIONS)"}}}}}
```

that produces the following results:

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":0,
    "params":{
      "q":"MEM_ED_NUMBER:136250 AND CM_TYPE:WEB_MOBILE",
      "json.facet":"{Level1:{type:terms,field:ENTRY_DATE,limit:100,facet:{Level2:{type:terms,field:NAME_URL,limit:100,facet:{sum:\"sum(PAGE_IMPRESSIONS)\",sum2:\"sum(PAGE_IMPRESSIONS)\"}}}}}",
      "indent":"true",
      "rows":"0",
      "wt":"json"}},
  "response":{"numFound":32,"start":0,"docs":[]
  },
  "facets":{
    "count":32,
    "Level1":{
      "buckets":[{
          "val":"2015-01-01T00:00:01Z",
          "count":2,
          "Level2":{
            "buckets":[{
                "val":"www.newarkadvocate.com",
                "count":2,
                "sum":7118768.0,
                "sum2":7118768.0}]}},
        {
          "val":"2015-02-01T00:00:01Z",
          "count":2,
          "Level2":{
            "buckets":[{
                "val":"www.newarkadvocate.com",
                "count":2,
                "sum":7458540.0,
                "sum2":7458540.0}]}},
        {
          "val":"2015-03-01T00:00:01Z",
          "count":2,
          "Level2":{
            "buckets":[{
                "val":"www.newarkadvocate.com",
                "count":2,
                "sum":7737596.0,
                "sum2":7737596.0}]}},
        {
          "val":"2015-04-01T00:00:01Z",
          "count":2,
          "Level2":{
            "buckets":[{
                "val":"www.newarkadvocate.com",
                "count":2,
                "sum":8968393.0,
```

What I would like to do is order it on ENTRY_DATE DESCENDING but I can't get it correct.

I have tried

```
http://webaddress:8994/solr/crossmedia/select?q=MEM_ED_NUMBER:136250%20AND%20CM_TYPE:WEB_MOBILE&sort=ENTRY_DATE%20desc&rows=0&wt=json&indent=true&json.facet={Level1:{type:terms,field:ENTRY_DATE,limit:100,facet:{Level2:{type:terms,field:NAME_URL,limit:100,facet:{sum:"sum(PAGE_IMPRESSIONS)",sum2:"sum(PAGE_IMPRESSIONS)"}}}}}
```

Which gives me the same result set, no order change.

I have tried

```
http://webaddress:8994/solr/crossmedia/select?q=MEM_ED_NUMBER:136250%20AND%20CM_TYPE:WEB_MOBILE&rows=0&wt=json&indent=true&json.facet={Level1:{type:terms,field:ENTRY_DATE,sort:"ENTRY_DATE%20desc",limit:100,facet:{Level2:{type:terms,field:NAME_URL,limit:100,facet:{sum:%22sum(PAGE_IMPRESSIONS)%22,sum2:%22sum(PAGE_IMPRESSIONS)%22}}}}}
```

Which gives me an error.

Can someone please help?

Thanks,
Bob

Here's the error message from the latest URL with fixed curly brace.

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":500,
    "QTime":0,
    "params":{
      "q":"MEM_ED_NUMBER:136250 AND CM_TYPE:WEB_MOBILE",
      "json.facet":" {Level1: {sort: {ENTRY_DATE: desc}, type:terms, field:ENTRY_DATE, limit:100, facet:{Level2: {type:terms,field:NAME_URL,limit:100,facet: {sum:\"sum(PAGE_IMPRESSIONS)\",sum2:\"sum(PAGE_IMPRESSIONS)\"}}}}}",
      "indent":"true",
      "rows":"0",
      "wt":"json"}},
  "response":{"numFound":32,"start":0,"docs":[]
  },
  "error":{
    "trace":"java.lang.NullPointerException\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.search.facet.FacetFieldProcessorNumeric$5.lessThan(FacetFieldProcessorNumeric.java:371)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.search.facet.FacetFieldProcessorNumeric$5.lessThan(FacetFieldProcessorNumeric.java:367)\r\n\tat org.apache.lucene.util.PriorityQueue.upHeap(PriorityQueue.java:258)\r\n\tat org.apache.lucene.util.PriorityQueue.add(PriorityQueue.java:135)\r\n\tat org.apache.lucene.util.PriorityQueue.insertWithOverflow(PriorityQueue.java:151)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.search.facet.FacetFieldProcessorNumeric.calcFacets(FacetFieldProcessorNumeric.java:397)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.search.facet.FacetFieldProcessorNumeric.process(FacetFieldProcessorNumeric.java:151)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.search.facet.FacetProcessor.processSubs(FacetRequest.java:267)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.search.facet.FacetProcessor.fillBucket(FacetRequest.java:354)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.search.facet.FacetQueryProcessor.process(FacetQuery.java:57)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.search.facet.FacetModule.process(FacetModule.java:87)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:255)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:143)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2064)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.execute(HttpSolrCall.java:654)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:450)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:227)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:196)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)\r\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)\r\n",
    "code":500}}
```

Here is my SOLR request:

```
http://webdev:8994/solr/crossmedia/select?q=MEM_ED_NUMBER:136250%20AND%20CM_TYPE:WEB_MOBILE&rows=0&wt=json&indent=true&json.facet=%20{Level1:%20{sort:%20{ENTRY_DATE:%20desc},%20type:terms,%20field:ENTRY_DATE,%20limit:100,%20facet:{Level2:%20{type:terms,field:NAME_URL,limit:100,facet:%20{sum:%22sum(PAGE_IMPRESSIONS)%22,sum2:%22sum(PAGE_IMPRESSIONS)%22}}}}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
http://webaddress:8994/solr/crossmedia/select?q=MEM_ED_NUMBER:136250%20AND%20CM_TYPE:WEB_MOBILE&rows=0&wt=json&indent=true&json.facet=
 {Level1:
   {sort: {ENTRY_DATE: desc},
    type:terms,
    field:ENTRY_DATE,
    limit:100,
    facet:{Level2:
       {type:terms,field:NAME_URL,limit:100,facet:
      {sum:%22sum(PAGE_IMPRESSIONS)%22,sum2:%22sum(PAGE_IMPRESSIONS)%22}}}}}
```

Comment: I copied your above URL, changed webaddress to the actual address and ran it and got the following error message.  See next answer.

Comment: fixed the level at which the sort must go, try now?

Comment: Got a different error this time.  It's posted below.  Thank you for taking the time and helping me on this issue.

Comment: damn, curly brace misplaced...fixed it (I think, im doing it in my head). You could edit your q instead of adding an answer each time or something, mabye

Comment: Still get an error.  I updated my original question with the latest error message.

Comment: put in there also the exact request you are sending to solr

Comment: Updated OQ with full SOLR URL (which is what I believe you were asking for)

Comment: I cannot obviously test with your schema etc, but just tried a similar query in a setup of mine and the sort works fine

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up using for my data for it to work correctly

```
http://webdev.auditedmedia.com:8994/solr/crossmedia/select?q=MEM_ED_NUMBER%3A136250+AND+CM_TYPE%3AWEB_MOBILE&rows=0&wt=json&indent=true&json.facet={%22Level1%22:{%22type%22:%22terms%22,%22field%22:%22ENTRY_DATE%22,%22limit%22:100,%22sort%22:{%22index%22:%22desc%22},%22facet%22:{%22Level2%22:{%22type%22:%22terms%22,%22field%22:%22NAME_URL%22,%22limit%22:100,%22facet%22:{%22sum%22:%22sum(PAGE_IMPRESSIONS)%22,%22sum2%22:%22sum(PAGE_IMPRESSIONS)%22}}}}}
```

The sort is part of level 1 and it's using Index rather than Entry_Date